# JMockit Mock an object inside while loop

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

I have a below test class method that I am writing a test for.

```java
  public String doSomething(Dependency dep) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
    String response;
    while ((response = dep.get()) != null) {
      content.append(response);
    }
    return content.toString();
  }
```

Below is the test case I have. Basically I want the `Dependency#get()` method to return `"content"` in the first iteration and `null` in the second.

```java
  @Test
  void test(@Mocked Dependency dep) {
    new Expectations() {
      {
        dep.get();
        result = "content";
        times = 1;
      }
    };
    Assertions.assertEquals("content", testSubject.doSomething(dep));
  }
```

However this results in JMockit throwing `Unexpected invocation to: Dependency#get()` error. If I remove the `times` field, my test runs in a forever loop.

How can I test this method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that JMockit apart from the `result` paramater can also set a `returns(args...)` method to which we can pass a series of arguments that it will expect sequentially. So modifying the test to this worked for me.

```
  @Test
  void test(@Mocked Dependency dep) {
    new Expectations() {
      {
        dep.get();
        returns("content", null);
        times = 2;   // limiting to mock only twice as only 2 values are provided in returns
      }
    };
    Assertions.assertEquals("content", testSubject.doSomething(dep));
  }
```